# Windows 10 & Java : Read/Write on raw drive

Tags: java, windows, binaryfiles, jna

I need to read and write binary data on an USB drive which is in "raw" format.

I tried a lot of things to read a buffer directly from the drive (which is mounted in windows but not navigeable). Last of them are with use of oshi-core :

```
SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();

    List<HWDiskStore> diskStore = si.getHardware().getDiskStores();
    for (HWDiskStore hwDiskStore : diskStore) {
        HWPartition disk = hwDiskStore.getPartitions().get(0);
        if (disk.getMountPoint().startsWith("G")) {
            String pathname = hwDiskStore.getName();
            System.err.println("pathname = " + pathname);
            Path diskRoot = (new File(pathname)).toPath();

            FileChannel fc = null;
            try {
                fc = FileChannel.open(diskRoot, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

                final ByteBuffer buf = createByteBuffer(1024);
                buf.position(0);

                int count = fc.read(buf);
                System.out.println("read count=" + count);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

When I do this I get an exception :

```
pathname = \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1\: Un périphérique attaché au système ne fonctionne pas correctement.
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:120)
at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292)
at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345)
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if you plugged it into a Linux box probably

Comment: Well I would prefer... but no choice. Windows 7/10 is my target !

Comment: There used to be an app called rawrite.exe but I never heard of rawread.exe…

Comment: At the bottom of a solution would probably be something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28314/Reading-and-Writing-to-Raw-Disk-Sectors) which you'd have to JNA-ise